# Add string at beginning and in-between of each line in a file

Tags: perl

I have a file with below content:

```
ii, aa;



    jj, bb; // this is a comment

    hh;
 kk; /*this is comment*/
```

I need to turn it into below format...

```
console.log(ii, aa);
console.log(jj, bb);
console.log(hh);
console.log(kk);
```

I have this part of the perl script

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$^I = '.bak'; # create a backup copy 

while (<>) {
   chop;
   s/^[^\r\n].*;*$/console.log($_);/g; # do the replacement
   print $_, "\n"; # print to the modified file
}
```

resulted

```
console.log(ii, aa;);

console.log(    );
console.log(  );
console.log(    jj, bb; // this is a comment);
console.log(    );
console.log(    hh;);
console.log( kk; /*this is comment*);
```

Any help in transforming this as per explained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
while (<>) {
    chop;
    next if /^\s*$/; # skip empty lines
    s/^\s+//; # remove leading whitespace
    s/;.*$//; # remove semi-colon and any comments;
    print "console.log($_);\n"; # print to the modified file
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can rely on there always being a single statement (and a semicolon) on every significant line of input, then this is a tidy way of writing a solution

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

while ( <DATA> ) {
    next unless s/;.*/);/;
    s/^\s*/console.log(/;
    print;
}

__DATA__
ii, aa;



    jj, bb; // this is a comment

    hh;
 kk; /*this is comment*/
```

#### output

```
console.log(ii, aa);
console.log(jj, bb);
console.log(hh);
console.log(kk);
```